# How to trigger react-router without Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I understand react-router has Link and clicking them reloads the entire page:

`<Link to="/projects/123">`

But in some cases I have raw HTML such as messages:

`Hey dude, please complete <a href="https://example.com/projects/123">https://example.com/projects/123</a> and dont forget to close them`

How do I give the same functionality to `a` tags?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `redirect` method of the [`Transition`](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Transition) object in the `onclick` handler for the anchor.